# Create a new column in python using mutilevel groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I am stuck a bit here. The given chart is something like this:

```
Zone    Code    Value
Dhk      Z1      2
Dhk      Z1      4
Dhk      Z2      6
Dhk      Z2      8
Raj      Z1      8
Raj      Z1     10
Raj      Z2     12
Raj      Z2     14
```

And the format I want to convert it to is:

```
Zone    Code    Value   Mean Value grouped by zone and code
Dhk      Z1       2                    3
Dhk      Z1       4 
Dhk      Z2       6                    7
Dhk      Z2       8
Raj      Z1       8                    9
Raj      Z1      10 
Raj      Z2      12                   13
Raj      Z2      14
```

Is this possible in Python?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: check my code on the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `transform` `mean` , then using `group` `head` with the result , and assign the new value to original dataframe by using `index` match , `fillna` with blank

```
s=df.groupby(['Zone','Code']).Value.transform('mean')
df['Mean Value grouped by zone and code']=s.groupby([df['Zone'],df['Code']]).head(1)
df['Mean Value grouped by zone and code'].fillna('',inplace=True)
df
Out[268]: 
  Zone Code  Value Mean Value grouped by zone and code
0  Dhk   Z1      2                                   3
1  Dhk   Z1      4                                    
2  Dhk   Z2      6                                   7
3  Dhk   Z2      8                                    
4  Raj   Z1      8                                   9
5  Raj   Z1     10                                    
6  Raj   Z2     12                                  13
7  Raj   Z2     14
```